# Get A Script To Work Using hostname To Grab URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to get this script to work and it's frustrating. I'm trying to improve the script by grabbing the URL instead of entering the domain manually.

Here is the original:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      makeSlider({
          url: "http://yourdomain.com/" // Add your blog URL
      });
</script>
```

Here is what I tried(and others similar to it):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      makeSlider({
          url: "http//" + window.location.hostname + /
      });
</script>
```

I even tried using a variable:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      var getDomain = "http//" + window.location.hostname + /,
      makeSlider({
            url: getDomain
      });
</script>
```

None of my attempts have worked.

Comment: I'd suggest you look in the browser error or debug console because it would have have showed you that you have a javascript syntax error and are missing quotes around the last `"/"`.  These kinds of simple to diagnose yourself errors really shouldn't be coming to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var getDomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/";
```